# Matlab import of .dm3 image files broken after recent GMS update

Tags: matlab, import, export, dm-script

I'm trying to read in dm3 files with Sigworth's Matlab script (ReadDMFile.m to be found [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43005-read-dm3-and-dm4-image-files?requestedDomain=true))

The script attempts to extract these tags:

- 'ImageList 2 ImageData Calibrations Dimension 1 Scale'
- 'ImageList 2 ImageData Calibrations Dimension 1 Units'
- 'ImageList 2 ImageData Dimensions 1'
- 'ImageList 2 ImageData Dimensions 2'
- 'ImageList 2 ImageData Dimensions 3'
- 'ImageList 2 ImageData Data'

But the cell ('output') that should contain the results, comes up empty.

This same script has no problems reading dm3 files that were recorded by the same hardware and saved on the same machine shortly before GMS3 had gotten an update (new library installed). I therefore suspect the problem is with the installation rather than with the script.

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds more like a *Matlab* question than a *DM-scripting* question. If the software version changed, and that changed the file-format, then there is nothing in *DM-scripting* which would fix the file for you.

However, you may consider going the opposite way and

- Have DM *export* the data in a matlab readable format
- Or have DM *export* the data in an intermediate format a matlab script could read.

Both options would be 'DM-scripts'. Possibly the easiest intermediate format would be a "data-only" format containing just the data values and no meta info. The meta info could be saved separately. The script to save an image in "data-only" is simply:

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
string path = "C:\\filename"
if ( !SaveAsDialog( NULL, "Please choose a saving location.", path, path ) ) exit(0)

img.SaveAsRawData( path )
Result( "\nFile saved as: " + path + ".dat" )
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a Matlab question, as the problems are caused by a change in DM. But indeed, it seems a new Matlab script reading DM might be needed. So far it looks like we'll be going for option two and export as tiff, that seems to work well, included for stacks.

Answer (score 0):

When looking into "how to fix" the Matlab script, it might be helpful to compare the two images (working/not working) loaded as a tag-structure.

A DM image is just a TagStructure like any TagGroup. Meta information is found "one hierachy layer up" to what you normaly get when you look at image tags.

The following script shows how to open a DM image as tagGroup:

```
string path = "C:\\test.dm3"
if ( !OpenDialog( NULL, "Please select the file.", path, path ) ) exit(0)

TagGroup tg = NewTagGroup()
if ( tg.TagGroupLoadFromFile( path ) )
    tg.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( path, 0 )
```

The `data-only` format stores the values in the data-type of the image with the data ordering:

```
Iterated over Z
   Iterated over Y
      Iterated over X
```

i.e. "line-by-line", then "plane-by-plane", and accordingly for higher dimensions.

Comment: Changing the Matlab script seems like the way to go then. Thanks, this is really useful.